# SPSS, syntax: How to categorize each 260 cases as a separate level in a single variable

Tags: r, syntax, spss

We are analyzing geological data on a set that has around ~26k measurements (elemental readings) of a seashell. An identical second measurement (isotope readings) took place, it only has a 100 data points (because that's how the machine works).

Now we are trying to (cross)label each 262 cases of the elemental reading (1) to first data point of the isotope reading (2). Thus cases 1-262 = 1, 263 - 525 = 2 and et cetera.

```
DO IF(MISSING(interval_element)).
COMPUTE id_element=$SYSMIS.
ELSE IF (interval_element >= 1 AND interval_element < 262).
COMPUTE id_element = 1.
ELSE IF (interval_element >= 263 AND interval_element < 526).
COMPUTE id_element = 2.

*etc. to a 100.*

END IF.
EXECUTE.'
```

Doing it manually is an option (see above), but we have a 100 data points thus doing this with a loop/repeat command has piqued our interest for the obvious reasons.

We looked at http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-loop-command/, but we didn't manage to grab a solution from there. And most posts found on this site are about different or between variables, whilst we want a new variable that identifies 262 cases per level (up to a 100).

We are curious on how to do this in SPSS syntax, and are also quite curious how to do it in R. We're not that experienced but we know it is a simple question, we are probably overlooking something small.

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT**

I think I figured out what the problem is. The thing is that we want the first 260 cases, without using the values. The reason I chose interval_element is because we want to segment the distances.

But looking at it now, it doesn't matter much if we aren't using its values. Using interval_element, we have 26k numbers ranging from [ .019926, 26.67770 ]). This explains why we have all one's, we never exceed the value of 262 in the data set.

Maybe I had to be a bit more clear, thought I was by saying cases instead of values, my bad.

**SOLUTION**

Using `id_element=1 + trunc(($CASENUM-0.1)/262)` gave NA's, after removing **-0.1** it worked just fine!

The variable interval_element is distance measured in mm, ordering it wasn't a problem.

@eli-k Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a more efficient way to do what you're doing:
    *creating an index variable.
    sort cases by interval_element.
    compute IEindex=$casenum.

```
recode IEindex
(1 thru 262=1)
(263 thru 524=2)
(525 thru 786=3)
.......
into id_element.
```

You'll still have to add 100 lines like this, to create 100 levels in variable id_element, so a more sophisticated approach is called for.
Now `loop` and `do repeat` are usually used to loop through sets of variables. since you only have one variable here, This isn't a classical looping problem.  So instead of looping, I suggest a simple calculation that determines `id_element` directly:

```
compute id_element=1 + trunc((IEindex-0.1)/262).
exe.
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I get all ones in the new variable. Not sure why we want to use trunc(), we want to split, not round them down as far as I know, right? 

A quick Google search left me with this site: http://spsstools.net/de/learning-syntax/. But there they don't loop/repeat the amount of cases that need to be redefined. They manually label them as well

Comment: Do you maybe have a R example?

Comment: this should work - try calculating a few values (like 262, 263, 500, 1000) with a simple calculator - you should only get 1 for values of 1 to 262... In any case see my edit for some extra background.

Comment: I added an R tag to your post, that should help get some R responses too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I figured out what the problem is. The thing is that we want the first 260 _cases_, without using the values. The reason I chose _interval_element_ is because we want to segment the distances. But looking at it now, it doesn't matter much if we aren't using its values.

Using interval_element, we have 26k numbers ranging from [ .019926, 26.67770 ]). This explains why we have all one's, we never exceed the value of 262 in the data set.

Maybe I had to be a bit more clear, thought I was by saying _cases_ instead of _values_, my bad.

Comment: please edit your question to clarify this, so I can edit the solution accordingly.

Comment: maybe all you need is this: `compute id_element=1 + trunc(($CASENUM-0.1)/262).`, but note - this will work the same regardless of the order of your cases, so you'd be better off using an index variable that corresponds to the original order of your measurements.

Comment: The variable _interval_element_ is distance measured in mm, ordering it shouldn't be a problem. 

At first I get NA's, but after removing *-0.1* in compute id_element=1 + trunc(($CASENUM)/262) it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure? that should put id_element=2 for row 262 instead of 1, id_element=3 for row 524 instead of 2 etc'.

Comment: Yea I checked it twice, wasn't sure why the `-0.1` was there. After removing that, it all worked. Using SPSS 23 fyi